# Oversized 300 DPI images

Tags: wkhtmltopdf

We have a to generate a Letter US PDF that holds the content of a student's transcript within HTML tables.

These transcripts have an header and footer images.

I was provided with 8.5 inches wide @ 300 DPI images. They are exactly 2550 pixels wide.

When I generate the PDF using these, the PDF doesn't seem to take the width of the images, or you could say the images are WAY TOO BIG.

I'm essentially just running this command:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --page-size "letter" "C:\Temp\content.html" --header-html "C:\Temp\header.html"  --header-spacing "0" --footer-spacing "0"  --footer-html "C:\Temp\footer.html"  "C:\Temp\transcripts\test.pdf"
```

My header/footer.html just has this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body style="margin:0px;">                  
    <div style="padding: 0px; margin: 0px; width: 100%; text-align: center">
        <img src="https://hostname/3_header.png">
    </div>                  
</body>
</html>
```

and my content.html is essentially just a

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <table>
        ....
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

You'll notice that I'm using `--page-size "letter"` option to set the PDF output size too.

It'll produce something like:

[image]

What am I doing wrong here ? I've tried everything from fiddling around the `--dpi` or `--image-dpi` or also `--zoom` options, but nothing made it good!

IF I take the same images and decrease there DPIs to 150, then it seems to be somewhat okay, but image quality seems to have decreased a little... These are official documents and would really need to be highdef when printed too...

I have no clue what to do here, honestly. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

p.s.: On MS Windows, tried both `wkhtmltopdf 0.12.2.1` and latest `0.12.6`: same results­.

Much thanks.
Pat